# Organising Data using Nested Generics in Java(Android)

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I am creating a music player app. I retrieve the data from the directory in a class named SongInfo which looks like this:

```
public class SongInfo {

//id of song
private long _ID;

//song name
private String title;

//artist name
private String artistName;

//album name
private String albumName;

//song duration
long  duration;

//year of release
private String year;

//constructor

//comparators to sort data
```

My app has a structure such that there is a

ArtistsFragment to show the List of Artists on clicking -> it Opens up Albums Fragment which has the List of Albums of the selected artist -> opens up Songs Fragment which has ArrayList of Songs of the selected album. What I end up doing instead is create a data structure of this sort:

```
//contains most of the info of the song
ArrayList<SongInfo> songs;

//contains an arrayList of songs  
ArrayList<ArrayList<SongInfo>> albums;

//contains an arraylist of albums    
Arraylist<ArrayList<ArrayList<SongInfo>>> artists;
```

which I am very sure is the wrong way to do it, cos what if I had more layers? I am looking for a better way to do this. I just need a hint, but an illustration/explanation would be awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: "organise this data into 3 different fragments such that: List of Artists -> Albums of the selected artist -> Songs of the selected album." Wouldn't it be nice if you could explain in just a fragment of a sentence what weird idea you have in your mind to a multitude of unknown people!  But I am afraid this makes sense only to you.

Comment: @MikeNakis I have added more info, hope it makes sense. Please let me know if you have any other doubts understanding the question.

Comment: Create a `Song` class that have a `List<SongInfo>` (named `infos`?) and an `Album` class that has a `List<Song>` (named `songs`?).

Comment: Don't you think this would essentially just hide this in the syntax? Can there be a better way to do this operation? Like using some parent - child relationships?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we start with these classes:

```
public static class Song
{
    String title;
    Artist artist;
    Album album;
    Song( String title, Artist artist, Album album ) 
        { this.title = title; this.artist = artist; this.album = album; }
    @Override public String toString() { return "Song: " + title; }
}

public static class Artist
{
    String name;
    Artist( String name ) { this.name = name; }
    @Override public String toString() { return "Artist: " + name; }
}

public static class Album
{
    String name;
    Album( String name ) { this.name = name; }
    @Override public String toString() { return "Album: " + name; }
}
```

Where:

- `Song` is what you are now calling with the rather unfortunate name `SongInfo`
- `Artist` is a class that you don't have yet, but you should. If you can't handle that, then whenever you see `Artist` just think of a `String` with an artist's name in it.
- `Album` is another class that you don't have yet, but you should. If you can't handle that, then whenever you see `Album` just think of a `String` with an album's title in it.

And suppose we start with this dataset:

```
    Artist artist1 = new Artist( "Artist1" );
    Artist artist2 = new Artist( "Artist2" );
    Set<Artist> artists = new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( artist1, artist2 ) );
    Album album1 = new Album( "Album1" );
    Album album2 = new Album( "Album2" );
    Set<Album> albums = new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( album1, album2 ) );
    Song song11a = new Song( "Song11a", artist1, album1 );
    Song song11b = new Song( "Song11b", artist1, album1 );
    Song song22a = new Song( "Song22a", artist2, album2 );
    Song song22b = new Song( "Song22b", artist2, album2 );
    List<Song> songs = Arrays.asList( song11a, song11b, song22a, song22b );
```

Then the following will give you what you want:

```
Collection<Song> getSongsByArtist( Collection<Song> songs, Artist artist )
{
    return songs.stream().filter( song -> song.artist == artist )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() );
}

Collection<Album> getAlbumsByArtist( Collection<Song> songs, Artist artist )
{
    return songs.stream().filter( song -> song.artist == artist )
        .map( song -> song.album ).collect( Collectors.toSet() );
}
```

And the following will give you everything you always wanted to know about your dataset but were afraid to ask:

```
Map<Song,Artist> artistsBySong = songs.stream()
    .collect( Collectors.toMap( Function.identity(), song -> song.artist ) );
Map<Song,Album> albumsBySong = songs.stream()
    .collect( Collectors.toMap( Function.identity(), song -> song.album ) );
Map<Artist,List<Song>> songsByArtist = songs.stream()
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( song -> song.artist ) );
Map<Album,List<Song>> songsByAlbum = songs.stream()
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( song -> song.album ) );
assert songs.stream().map( song -> song.album )
    .collect( Collectors.toSet() ).equals( albums );
assert songsByAlbum.keySet().equals( albums );
```